# Vue custom (cli ?) project generator

Tags: javascript, vue.js

All my VueJS projects use at the beginning the same baseline :

- Vuex
- Vue Router
- Immutable.js
- MathJS
- MomentJs
- ChartJS

Plus, all my projects have quite the same "index.js" file.

Is there a way to have a command line (preferably based on Vue CLI) that can generate a project with a pre-coded "index.js" file and a package.json with those above dependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wanting to use the [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create) to create a project. However, you additionally want some default npm packages to be installed and imported into your `index.js` file.

Answer: no. this functionality does not exist (currently)

Some Suggestions:

1. Open a feature request [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues). If you did do a feature request, you should descibe it in a more general way. For example 'allow the ability to specify npm packages on project creation' opposed to specifically installing ChartJS, Moment and the other ones. That's too specific, that will get shot down and closed in a heart beat.
2. Create a repo with the project structure and packages you want and always start from that repo (opposed to using vue cli)
3. Write your own custom node cli to interface with vue cli that handels your extra steps for you. You could easily write a node (console program) that executes the steps you want. Basically, create the vue project, npm install what you need, generate an index.js with your package imports.

I think the easiest route is to just create an empty vue project how you want it. Save that repo as 'vue-boilerplate' or something and just always start off with that empty project opposed to doing `vue create` every time.

In my personal opinion, I think going through all this to npm install 3 packages and add the imports to a js file isn't entirely worth it unless you find yourself creating a massive amount of projects that will all require the exact same setup.

Angular has a similar idea called [schematics](https://angular.io/guide/schematics) but I do not see an equivilant within Vue as of yet.

Comment: Thank you. To be honest I'm not looking for the easiest route but the for the most automatised one

Comment: Remember to upvote if this helps you. -- There really isn't one. You're going to have to make your own repo with the custom setup you're after and work with that one. Technically speaking, you could fork the Vue CLI repo and code this up. But, that seems like a waste of time unless you get the Vue CLI team to sign off on it (so it can be merged into the repo and used by others)